CSS File Loads with 200 OK but Styles Are Not Applied in React App AWS EC2
I'm working on a React app where the CSS file is loaded successfully with a 200 OK status from my NGINX server on EC2, but none of the styles from the file are being applied to the elements on the page.
Here are the details:
My index.html includes the following line to load the CSS:
<link href="/static/css/main.7bda9ab3.css" rel="stylesheet">
The CSS file is hosted at http://X/static/css/main.7bda9ab3.css, and the React app is hosted at http://X/.

The Network tab in Chrome DevTools shows that the CSS file is being imported with a 200 OK status.
The CSS file is not empty, and I've confirmed that it contains the correct styles.
I'm not using CSS Modules, and there are no inline styles overriding the CSS.
I've ruled out browser caching as an issue.
I've used a static URL in the index.html file as an alternative, still not working.
All the inline styles in my files are being applied just OK, but not the ones specifically in the .css files.
My React pages and components (/home , /contact) each have their own css files /home.css and /contact.css. The consolidated css file main.7bda9ab3.css which i get after building the app has all the styles combined


I've tried hosting a different React application on AWS EC2, and I face the same error. With this application, the styles apply just fine to the local build and Netlify build.

Does the browser console have anything to say about this? What does the Content-Type header of the response contain?

Says text/plain for the css file

Just compared it to my local, and it seems it should be text/css. Woah. How do I enforce that?

My mime.types in /etc/nginx/mime.types already has  text/css                                         css

Added a include /etc/nginx/mime.types to my nginx.conf file, and this way, genius C3roe solved my issue.
